# Nginx 502 error but application is running on localhost

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I deployed a Node API to a Digital Ocean droplet 6 months ago, using Nginx as a reverse proxy. It worked fine until last night, when a too intensive request crashed my app, and I got a 502 error.

I rebooted my app and Nginx, but I still got the 502 error. After a while I tried to access my app through a proxy (Hola chrome extension), and the error disappeared, even after I disconnected the proxy.

The problem is that it's still showing the error for all other users. My app is an API at back.influencerz.io

Here's what works:

- `http://X.X.X.X:5000/` (ip address, no HTTPS)
- `curl http://localhost:5000` (from the VPS itself)

Here's my Nginx config:

```
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name back.influencerz.io;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/back.influencerz.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/back.influencerz.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

}
```

My app is a Node app using Koa. Here's how the server is created:

```
const app = new Koa()
app.listen(5000)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you still having a problem? Your app seems to be working properly.

Comment: Seems like it works for you too, but it's down for most users. (https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/back.influencerz.io.html). How are you accessing the app? In the browser, with curl?

Comment: I tried it both ways and have no problem.

Comment: This is odd. Why Nginx would work for only some users ?

Comment: If someone still got the 502 Bad Gateway error, then check your nginx logs to find out why. As for the down detector web site, that's just because you don't answer on HTTP but only HTTPS.